# Split Function in hive on JSONS

Tags: json, regex, hive, bigdata

I'm handing JSON arrays in hive.I know that it can be handled with JSON serde as well but i want to do it with get_json_object or json_tuple and the regular expressions. so i was follwing  the link http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2014/04/16/using-explode-and-lateral-view-in-hive/

It gives the Json File like this
    `{"key1":"0","key2":"11.800","info":"[{\"id\":\"1234\",\"v\":\"3\"},{\"id\":\"5678\",\"v\":\"3\"}]","key3":"3"}`
Why it need to have slashes in front of id and every other value??.The Observation Are like below

[JSON With REGEX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXmBh.png)

When we add the split on the regex we got from the above result we get the below things
`["{\"id\":\"1234\",\"v\":\"3\"}","{\"id\":\"5678\",\"v\":\"3\"}"]`

If i remove the slashes in my source Json file ebrything is coming as null.What is the possible way to get out of this.

Comment: it's escaping the double quotes that are inside the *value* of the key "info". Why not single quotes, I know not. What are you trying to get out of that string?

Comment: To read the data in hive these are some of the ways .I just want the exploded  key value pairs in the form of strings because these will only work for me.

Answer (score 2):

The object you are seeing is valid JSON, it just so happens in this case that the value of the key *info* is a string (that looks like more JSON, confusingly) Not an object, array, or number, but a string.  Since this string has some double quotes in it, they are escaped.

to show this:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({"key1":"0","key2":"11.800","info":"[{\"id\":\"1234\",\"v\":\"3\"},{\"id\":\"5678\",\"v\":\"3\"}]","key3":"3"}));
```

result:

[image]